# Android: How to implement a Vertical scroll view with Multiple Horizontal rows inside of it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-scrollview

[image]

**strong text**

Hi All,
I need to get some help to implement implement a Vertical scroll view with Multiple Horizontal rows inside of it, this is what I have so far, any help or hint would be highly appreciated

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/threeByThreeTable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mygallery1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        />

                </HorizontalScrollView>

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mygallery2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        />


                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mygallery3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        />


                </HorizontalScrollView>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your TableLayout inside a ScrollView instead of a LinearLayout. Just keep in mind that a ScrollView can only have one child.

Comment: that stops the horizonal scrolling!! I need something like Netflix app

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `ListView` and remove the lines between the items? Seems like that would work much better than rolling your own view

Comment: Hi Hamy, ListView instead of scrollView?

Comment: Yup, but you need to redo the rest of the layout too. A ListView already has vertical scrolling a repeated horizontal list of items. You would need to implement a custom layout for each list item (which is fairly simple) that includes a HorizontalScrollView, and then you would have vertical and horizontal scroll

Comment: would you mind if you kinda edit it for me, I would truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

- Put a Vertical Linear Layout inside your ScrollView
- Inside the vertical linear layout, create your HorizontalScrollViews.

It should work probably, please let me know if you have questions.